# Check number of posts edited

Tags: discussion, editing

The **Strunk & White** badge is awarded for editing 80 posts.

I know I have edited a lot of posts (not quite 80) but I don't know where to find an exact number and if it's even possible.

Is there any way of a user checking the number of posts they have edited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New answer - looks like they added this or I missed it looking before:

https://movies.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all

Currently shows you at 86 edits...

Answer (score 4):

In your user profile, under activity, if you look at revisions, you can see that you have 103 revisions (as of 9/6/12), but this includes tag edits which are not posts. You could thumb through the 6 pages of revisions to count just the post revisions... not terribly efficient, but I think it would get you the info you want.

Answer (score 1):

I remember the old review had a section close to the bottom that let you know badge status, but with the new review section this seems to be gone.

Only other thing I can suggest is under your user information, click "Activity" and swap to the "revisions" tab, it tells you how many total revisions you have had including tag edits.