# Should MSO related questions allowed on this meta?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, migration, meta

I have seen many questions (above 30 ) on http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com which are already present on http://meta.stackoverflow.com . 
e.g

1. [How to format a link in a comment?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/661/how-to-format-a-link-in-a-comment)
2. [Check number of posts edited](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/628/check-number-of-posts-edited)

This questions nothing to do with Meta.movies . [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) says question related to http://movies.stackexchange.com are allowed only.

- Then why do we allow these type of questions?
- Shouldn't we delete or migrate this questions to http://meta.stackoverflow.com.
- Should we flag this type of questions for deletion or migration?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89228/which-meta-am-i-supposed-to-post-on

Comment: `Posting on a child meta is absolutely fine!The Stack Exchange team monitors all of the child metas.`

Comment: Also related http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/697/is-it-necessary-for-a-new-user-to-visit-meta-so-first-before-posting-in-meta-mov

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meta.Mmovies is one of the means by which users of M&TV can get support.  Many users here may not even be aware of MSO.

MSO is a strange site, acting as both general support for Stackoverflow but also for Stackexchange as a whole.  It can be a confusing place to send new people to ask support questions.

I tend to try to answer support questions here, but also make people aware of MSO so they can see existing questions and answers.  I do not think it is very friendly to just close or migrate such questions, but does no harm to make people aware of MSO when answering.

It is not as if this site has endless general support questions on it.

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat an interesting topic to discuss. On the one hand, you have the consolidation of material into one location. On the other, you have users that may **never** visit meta.so but may frequent ours.  These little questions are, imho, okay to have on our meta since meta.so is so freaking huge and alien to most visitors here.